# Exchange web services API - Get all mailboxes

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there a way to get all the existing mailboxes in exchange? I need this to be able to get all the tasks from all mailboxes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the web service API itself. You would need to look at the Get-Mailbox cmdlet in Powershell.